# Flutter audioplayers plugin error on xcode (Module 'audioplayers' not found)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

When I test it on iOS it works fine but when I try to archive on XCode it give me the following error:

> Module 'audioplayers' not found

I use  [audioplayers `0.13.5`](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

As you can see from my pubspec file I have the latest flutter and everything is ok but I don't know why I get this error.

I also tried many thing like following solution :

```
brew install cocoapods
pod setup
```

and I also deleted  iOS folder and install it again.

my **pubspec.yaml**

```
    name: mohammad
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intro_slider: ^2.2.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  device_info: ^0.4.1+1
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  wifi_info_plugin: ^1.0.6
  # connectivity: ^0.4.5+3
  flutter_udid: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.18+1
  audioplayers: ^0.13.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  flutter_svg: ^0.15.0

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.jpeg"
  android: true
  ios: true

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/mohammad.png
    - assets/new-word.png
    - assets/open-book.png
    - assets/icon/icon.jpeg
    - assets/elearning.png
    - assets/messenger.png
    - assets/icon/facebook.svg
    - assets/icon/instagram.svg
    - assets/icon/snapchat.svg
    - assets/icon/youtube.svg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: bahij
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/bahij.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

my **flutter info**

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.2
    19C57, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
    version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.0)
```

Comment: what error it gives when you run this command `flutter build ios` ?

Comment: It give no error,  like i said it just give error when I want to make archive and release the app from xcode to app-store

Comment: provide the whole error log

Comment: this is just the error from xcode
`Module 'audioplayers' not found`

Comment: after the pod update command we sometime requires to these steps ->   deleting the `Derived Data` and `clean the build project folder` and restart the Xcode again and then archive it might solve it, and please make sure you're opening `.xcworkspace` folder in Xcode

Comment: I tried everything but still no luck

Comment: check the Target Membership of audioplayers, it should be public.

Comment: Where can i find that ?

Comment: Thank you so much  actually it i wasn't opening .xcworkspace file from Xcode that was making the problem , because in vscode when you right click on ios folder and click on open in xcode it does not open .xcworkspace i think that should be fixed

Comment: @armancodex Did you find any solution?

Comment: yes the problem is do not open ios folder from vs code , go to xcode and open .xcworkspace file you should open this file if not you will get to lots of errors

Answer (score 28):

After a lot of search i found the solution which it was a very annoying.

For me the problem was when i opened the ios folder i was on Visual Studio Code and like you will do right click on it and choose open with Xcode but that is a problem because it will open wrong file you will think it is correct because at first there will be no error .

So the correct way to do it
 **Go to ios folder and open .xcworkspace file.**

Hope this will help others :)

Answer (score 4):

Only thing that worked for me:

**In ios folder:**

```
pod clean
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
```

Make sure the `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder, and `Runner.xcworkspace` files are all gone.

Go up one folder to the project `root` and run the command:

```
flutter build ios
```

**The above command should setup and do everything needed for iOS to work as expected**

After the build succeeds, it should have downloaded the correct pods, created the `Runner.xcworkspace` file again and the `Podfile.lock` will also exist again.

Open `XCode` and open the `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` project file

Answer (score 3):

For me, my POD target version and Runner target version were not the same. Making both the POD and Runner target versions the same fixed it.

[More info](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/308)

Comment: This did it for me, after adjusting the target version in XCode I needed to manually updated the Podfile target.